# How to make a 'object' with multiple variables/values in it in a bash script

Tags: bash

I am trying to make a dummy character for a project, & I don't know how give it multiple values (i.e. hp, atk, def, etc.) [Sorry if this is an obvious answer, I'm still new at this.]

I've tried using case like this, but actually thinking about it for a bit, I realized this could give me lots of problems when I try to add more than one:

```
$npc=1

case $npc in
    1)
    name="NPC"
    hp=100
    atk=20
    def=10
    ;;

   2)
   npctype="ERROR"
   ;;
esac
```

Comment: Associative arrays are the closest thing native bash has, but it's more typical to have one array per data type and use an object identifier as the key to index into it. That's not OO practice, but bash _isn't an object-oriented language_; you can't expect first-class support for a different paradigm's concepts. (I've seen some libraries that try to build an OO layer on top of bash, but do not at all recommend any of them).

Comment: The big problem with bash data structures is that they're not nestable. So you can't have an array of associative arrays, so no easy way to have a collection of characters. You're essentially forced into programming like BASIC or Fortran from the 60's and 70's. I wouldn't recommend using bash for a project like this.

Comment: Even arrays and associative arrays aren't real data structures (hence the no-nesting): they are more like syntactic sugar for working with similarly named variables.

Answer (score 0):

Bash is not an object-oriented language; trying to make it act like one is a lot of completely unnecessary pain.

Registering a new character, then, might be done with a function like:

```
declare -a names hps atks defs
declare -A ids

add_char() {
  local name id hp atk def
  name=$1; hp=$2; atk=$3; def=$4
  if [[ ${ids[$name]} ]]; then
    echo "Character $name already exists; cannot add" >&2
    return 1
  fi
  id=${#names[@]}  # Get new id based on length of "names"
  ids[$name]=$id
  names[$id]=$name
  hps[$id]=$hp
  atks[$id]=$atk
  defs[$id]=$def
}
```

... called as:

```
add_char Gary 20 5 2
add_char Sam 30 9 5
```

... resulting in:

```
$ declare -p names hps atks defs ids
declare -a names=([0]="Gary" [1]="Sam")
declare -a hps=([0]="20" [1]="30")
declare -a atks=([0]="5" [1]="9")
declare -a defs=([0]="2" [1]="5")
declare -A ids=([Gary]="0" [Sam]="1" )
```